# ¿Qué significa "poner pegas a algo"?

Tags: locuciones, significado-en-contexto

El contexto es el de un anuncio erótico:

> Soy muy obediente y me mojo con mucha facilidad. Ven y comeme entre las piernas, no le pongo [pegas](https://dle.rae.es/pega#SKLXYyh) a nada.

¿Puede significar *no me opongo a nada*?¿Cuál podria ser el posible origen de esa locución?

Comment: Locuciones no tienen etimologia. Son palabras que la tienen.

Comment: @Lambie Gracias. Ya corrigí la pregunta en respuesta a su comentario.

Comment: "pega" en este caso (en sentido figurado) toma el significado de "adhesivo" o "cola de pegar" (en inglés, "glue") .... de modo que "poner pegas" se refiere a hacer cosas que _frenan_ o que se oponen a algo.  Una expresión equivalente es "poner(le) trabas" a algo (o en el contexto de tu pregunta, la negación: "no ponerle trabas a nada")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- No (le) pongo ninguna objeción.
- No le hago asco a nada.
- Voy a todas.
- Sin inhibiciones.
- No voy a poner ningún inconveniente.

Otro ejemplo: A alguien le gusta más el ron, pero un matón (le) trajo whisky, entonces ese alguien dice: *como* (yo) (le) **ponga pegas**, *fijo*(=con toda seguridad) *que se mosquea*(=enfada, cabrea, enerva) <=Si es que el bully nota que no le gusta/pone mala cara por lo que trajo, entonces se va a enojar, entonces lo tolera por esa ocasión y va a disimular.

El origen es el juego de cartas. Un jugador marca las cartas con pegamento y el que no conoce el truco le cuesta ganar, es decir, al jugador al que se le **ponen pegas** tiene dificultad para ganar, es decir, se la ponen difícil, le ponen una dificultad mayor por su desconocimiento.

Entonces, en tu ejemplo, si dice que no le pone pegas a nada, quiere decir que **no va a poner dificultades** en relación a eso mismo que está ofreciendo o a lo que sea que le soliciten después, no va a tener reparos.